# Change array keys to lowercase

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a nifty php solution to replace a standard forloop. i dont care at all about the inner workings of my normalize method.

Here is my code:

```
$pairs=[];
foreach($items as $key => $val){
    $key = $this->normalizeKey($key);
    $pairs[$key] = $val;
}

private function normalizeKey($key)
{
    // lowercase string
    $key = strtolower($key);

    // return normalized key
    return $key;
}
```

I'd like to learn the PHP language a bit better. I thought `array_walk` would be nice to use, but that operates on the values and not the keys.

I am looking for a PHP array method that can perform this code instead of a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Post the normalizeKey method

Comment: @Mihai done its up

Comment: -> `array_change_key_case()` <-

Comment: @Rizier123 updated question

Comment: If this is just an example and you want to know how to apply some code to every key of an array then you haven't chosen a very good example?! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change array keys from uppercase to lowercase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315447/how-to-change-array-keys-from-uppercase-to-lowercase)

Comment: @jkushner please look at my updated answer. It seems there was a problems with original

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can normalise the keys and store them and their corresponding values in a temporary array and assign it to your original `$pairs` array.

Like so:

```
$normalised = [];

foreach($pairs as $key => $value) {
    $normalised[$this->normalizeKey($key)] = $value;
};

$pairs = $normalised;
```

Edit 2022: Or better yet, use @Sherif's answer as it uses a standand library function

Comment: _The function may be defined as (&$value, $key) but not (&$value, &$key).  Even though PHP does not complain/warn, it does not modify the key._

Comment: @AbraCadaver  I just noticed. It doesn't even throw an error. Thanks! I'll notify the OP

Comment: @Sherif It's not _undefined behavior_, it just does not work the way intended.

Comment: Modified answer and it works with any implementation of `normalizeKey` method

Answer (score 16):

You want [`array_change_key_case`](http://php.net/array-change-key-case)

```
$pairs = array_change_key_case($items);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, though it requires three functions.  You can replace `strtolower()` with whatever since this can already be done with `array_change_key_case()`:

```
$pairs = array_combine(array_map('strtolower', array_keys($items)), $items);
```

- Get the keys from `$items`
- Map the array of keys to `strtolower()`
- Combine the new keys with `$items` values

You can also use an anonymous function as the callback if you need something more complex.  This will append `-something` to each key:

```
$pairs = array_combine(array_map(function ($v) {
                                     return $v . '-something';
                                 },
                       array_keys($items)), $items);
```